# add a back button in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets, back-button

I have `3 jsp pages(index.jsp, result1.jsp,result2.jsp)` and one `servlet`. Processing is being done as below:

index.jsp

```
<form method="post" action="MYSERVLET" >
<input type="text" name="studentname" id="studentname"/>
<input type="submit" value="click" />// goes to a servlet named as MYSERVLET
</form>
```

MYSERVLET

```
 String t=request.getParameter("studentname");
------fetching data from database and sending to result1.jsp------

      String nextJSP = "/result1.jsp";
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
      dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

result1.jsp

//retrieving data from servlet and displaying data in `result1.jsp` and also passing the same value to `result2.jsp`

```
out.println(retrieved result from servlet);
<a  href="result2.jsp?somestring=<%out.println(retrieved result from servlet);%>"> <%out.println(retrieved result from servlet);%></a>// after clicking on "retrieved result from servlet" i am passing this retrieved value to another jsp result2.jsp and also retrieving some data from database as follows:
```

result2.jsp

```
String w=request.getParameter("somestring");
out.println(w);
```

I want to give a `back button here (in result2.jsp)` so that after clicking `back button` it will take me to `result1.jsp` where i can see the previously displayed data`(out.println(retrieved result from servlet);)`. But when i click browser back button(in result2.jsp) then each time alert is coming `"Confirm Form Resubmission"`  and then i am reloading that page to see `(out.println(retrieved result from servlet);)`,i want to avoid this alert, how can i avoid it? How can i straightly see that page without any alert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your problem lies in the "forward" action you put in your servlet. "Forwarding" happens only on the server, and the browser has no idea of what is going on on the server. In fact, you should see "MYSERVLET Url" in the url bar even if you're on result1 page. So when you go on result2.jsp, clicking "back" will only bring you again on the Servlet url, not the "result1.jsp" one. And since your servlet is the target of a form submission, you get that alert.

To avoid this, you should try something like "redirect" or "sendRedirect" instead of "forward" in your servlet. In that case your browser will be aware of the change of address and you can use back button as well.

But please note that with a redirect all the request data you send to your servlet cannot be passed directly to result1.jsp, you should save them in Session. Try and read [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181).

Answer (score 1):

Please hold all the data in session on 1st page itself by using `session.setAttribute("name",value);`and after landing to the second page, on the click of button specify the address of firstPage without any data and to display the previous data on first page, use `session.getAttribute("name");`
So that every time you switch between pages, it'll reload the page and get the session values.